# Play video files in VLC media player from behind HTTP basic authentication URLs without a password

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, google-chrome-extensions, automator

I regularly open HTTP URLs and play them directly in VLC media player, using the "Open Network..." option. Unfortunately, the URLs are behind HTTP basic authentication (they require a username and password) and VLC media player doesn't have a way to remember the credentials.  Basically, it's a pain to type the password each time.

I'm on Mac OS X, so I tried to use Automator to create a text-based Service that runs a shell script like this:

```
user=USERNAME
pass=PASSWORD

if [[ "${f}" =~ \:\/\/ ]]; then
  /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -f \
   $(echo $f | sed "s/\:\/\//\:\/\/$user\:$pass\@/")
fi
```

but when I right click on a link (browser agnostic), from what I can tell, it sends the service the display text, not the actual URL.

My other thought was just to create a Chrome extension with only a context menu item, but after googling around a bit, it seems Chrome can't run arbitrary shell scripts (probably for good reason).

How can I make it work?

*Like a way to get VLC media player to remember the password, but it doesn't use the Mac OS X keychain...