# Open password protected http stream with VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, http

I want to stream a video / media file that is hosted by a http server, but the webserver protects the file with [HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). The GUI asks for for the credentials on every opening of the stream.

This is quite annoying. Can the password be saved somehow?

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/337020/play-video-files-in-vlc-media-player-from-behind-http-basic-authentication-urls

Answer (score 7):

Not really saved, but you can enter the credentials in the URL itself:

When your media file URL is `http://server.com/my_media_file.mkv`, then simply add `http://<user>:<password>@server.com/my_media_file.mkv`.

**The authentication tokens must not contain whitespace** - VLC cannot process that.

Comment: Arghh, this won't work for SFTP :-( http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

Answer (score 0):

> The authentication tokens must not contain whitespace

Did someone try %20 which is the standard HTTP encoding for 32, the ASCII code for the space character?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1097612)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).